# Finding and trying to understand the technology used behind the scene

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, overlay

Sorry if the question is a bit out of place but don't know any better since i'm a complete beginner.

What i'm trying to say is let's take for example this site

https://exp-ion.lusion.co/

I am trying to "decode" what libraries and technologies are used behind the scene so i can learn more about them and try to replicate the same effects.
Is it in any way possible to get "hints" on how things are done?

Tried looking up the source code, tried inspecting various elements. I get that the scene is done using threejs library. What about the scroll ladder? What about the text?

Thank you in advance for any tips and tricks.

Comment: That site is completely unusable.

Comment: What do you mean, is a bit slow but loads

Comment: Well, it didn't work in FF, and I couldn't even move the mouse around in Chrome without it shuddering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Wappalyzer, they have a browser extension you can install that let's you see most of the technologies used in a site.

Comment: the extension looks pretty nice, tried in different websites and it does show some of the technology used but wanted something a bit more specific.